# as a field in a [mysql select query] to get set of array data

Tags: mysql

How to fix this mysql query

```
SELECT no, name,
(SELECT chapter, max FROM table2 WHERE name = user.name AND max = 10) 
  as sub_array1,
(SELECT chapter, max FROM table2 WHERE name = user.name AND max = 20) 
  as sub_array2
FROM user ORDER by exp DESC
```

example expected out result:

the current query returns me Operand should contain 1 column(s)

basically i want to create something like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
no    | name    |  sub_array1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     |myname   |  sub_array1[0][chapter]=chapter_1,  sub_array1[0][max]=100
      |         |  sub_array1[1][chapter]=chapter_2,  sub_array1[1][max]=70
      |         |  ...
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2     |myname_2 |  sub_array1[0][chapter]=chapter_1,  sub_array1[0][max]=100
      |         |  sub_array1[1][chapter]=chapter_2,  sub_array1[1][max]=50
      |         |  sub_array1[2][chapter]=chapter_3,  sub_array1[2][max]=60
```

Actual query

```
SELECT 
  no, name, maxcombo, exp, level, location,
  (
    (SELECT chapter, MAX(score) as max, name 
     FROM chapter_test_progress 
     WHERE name = user.name AND type = 'vocabulary' GROUP BY chapter
    )
  ) as user_chapter_test_statuses,
  (
    (SELECT chapter, MAX(score) as max, name 
     FROM chapter_test_progress 
     WHERE name = user.name AND type = 'kanji' GROUP BY chapter
    )
  ) as user_chapter_test_status_kanjis
FROM 
  user 
ORDER by 
  exp DESC 
LIMIT $offset, $rowPerPage
```

Thank You,

Comment: Sorry, actually there is no && in the query, that is mistype in the post not in the code ... still same error... :(

Comment: Can you post the actual query and table definition?

Comment: I just posted the actual query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I correctly understand the structure of your database, but this should do it:

```
SELECT U.no, U.name, S.chapter, S.max
FROM user U,
         (SELECT CP.chapter, MAX(CP.score) max, CP.name FROM chapter_test_progress CP GROUP BY name, chapter) S
WHERE U.name = S.name
GROUP BY U.name, S.chapter;
```

The test data I've used:

```
CREATE TABLE `chapter_test_progress` (
  `chapter` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert  into `chapter_test_progress`(`chapter`,`score`,`name`) values ('ch_1',10,'alice'),('ch_1',20,'alice'),('ch_2',10,'bob'),('ch_2',50,'bob'),('ch_1',100,'alice'),('ch_2',100,'alice'),('ch_1',200,'bob'),('ch_2',200,'bob');

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `no` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`no`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert  into `user`(`no`,`name`) values (1,'alice'),(2,'bob');
```

You should normalize your database.

Comment: hello, thank you so much. but I think the data set I will get from your query is not what I want.
how can i normalize the database? I'm a newbie :(

Comment: You should update your question with what you want to achieve and some sample of your data (something similar to my answer). This way people will understand easily what is your problem and be more eager to help you.